# Can you use PARSE with MySQL database (Joomla website)?

Tags: mysql, ios, database, parse-platform

I see that PARSE can be used to provide back-end support for your iOS app. However, many apps are extensions of existing websites; for example, say you have an existing dating website that is a Joomla site with MySQL database. Obviously you would want your app to be able to read and write to the EXISTING MySQL database.  Can PARSE play a role in your App's development (API for website/MySQL) or is it of no use in this situation?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse can provide a number of services and you can also use your existing backend. You could even use cloud code to call your existing backend.

Comment: So does this obviate the need for something like AFNetworking?

Comment: That depends. Running parse to communicate to another backend isn't efficient.

Comment: True.  So from my research I have concluded the following.  BaaS services (like Parse or StackMob) are really for novice developers looking for a quick back-end for basic photo sharing and social Apps.  The problem for full-powered Apps are 1) you don't get access to the actual database (can't run SQL) 2) only free up to a point and 3) usage stats are done for you (Data Scientists cringe). KUMULOS looked so promising for auto-generating web APIs from from what I can tell...nobody actually works there. .... AFNetworking it is!!!

Comment: @Cybernetic I am also looking for same but could not find something useful. please help if you have find the way to accomplish that.